# How to get current user in interceptors and retrieve its resources in controllers

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring MVC project and I want to implement my own authentication interceptor. It looks like this:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepo usersRepo;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) return true;
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;

        if (handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Authenticated.class) == null) return true;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) return reject(response);

        Long id = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
        if (id == null) return reject(response);

        User user = usersRepo.findOne(id);
        if (user == null) return reject(response);

        RequestContext.CURRENT_USER.set(user);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        RequestContext.CURRENT_USER.remove();
    }

    private boolean reject(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setStatus(403);
        return false;
    }
}
```

`RequestContext.CURRENT_USER` is a `ThreadLocal<User>`.

In the controller, I want to retrieve orders of the current user:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrdersController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Authenticated
    public Collection<Order> index() {
        Collection<Order> orders = RequestContext.CURRENT_USER.get().getOrders();
        return orders;
    }

}
```

It gives me `Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: myapp.models.User.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session`.

I think that's because Hibernate has closed the database session when it's done the job finding the current `User` in the interceptor, and thus it's unable to use that `User` to load `Order`s in another session. But I really don't want to hit database again. How can I load current user in interceptor and reuse that user instance to load more resources?

Comment: _"But I really don't want to hit database again."_ _"How can I load current user in interceptor and reuse that user instance to load more resources"_ That's quite a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the orders collection before storing the User in the thread local. Call

```
user.getOrders();
```

before

```
RequestContext.CURRENT_USER.set(user);
```

Or you can store just user id. When you need orders of current user retrieve fresh User

```
public Collection<Order> index() {
    User user = usersRepo.findOne(RequestContext.CURRENT_USER.get());
    Collection<Order> orders = user.getOrders();
    return orders;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want to load orders for each and every request.

Comment: Then reread the user. Use repo to find the same user by id (you can use the stored User's id) adn get orders from the newly retrieved user

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying this approach although I don't like the idea of hitting database twice with exactly identical queries.

Comment: Then you can create a separate query - getOrdersByUserId and place it to ordersRepo. Then just use the query passwing id of the current user

Comment: That's always a fallback option, but since I have a navigation property, why should I use a fallback? Oh I hate java.